# Meaning of the phrase "the fact that"

Tags: meaning

> We can rightfully take pride in the fact that this day has been recognised universally by the UN as International Mother Language Day. — [The Daily Star](https://www.thedailystar.net/editorial/news/language-martyrs-day-2048397)

What is the meaning of the phrase "the fact that"? What does it actually mean in a word? Is this phrase a conjunction?

Comment: What is a "fact"?

Comment: Thie phrase to look at is *in the fact*, not "the fact that." *That* links to the next words, not to "the fact." The sentence works without "in the fact": "We can take pride that this day..."

Comment: I think it's ironic that the name chosen by the UN should be [so non-idiomatic](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+mother+language+is%2Cmy+mother+tongue+is%2C&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmy%20mother%20language%20is%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmy%20mother%20tongue%20is%3B%2Cc0) in the "biggest" language on the planet! Native Anglophones *speak English as their mother **tongue*** (we live in our "motherland", but we don't speak our "mother language").

Comment: We can rightfully take pride in **[this fact / this]**: this day has been recognised universally by the UN as International Mother Language Day. 'this fact' is here a determiner phrase or noun phrase. Solitary 'this' is a nominalisation.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean "the fact that" like "You say that, but the fact that this is like that means this", then in my personal experience, "the fact that" would not be the contraction. Rather, "but" would be the conjunction there. The phrase is used when saying that a particular fact influences your judgment. The speaker is taking into account the stated fact in their statement.

Comment: Sorry. I'm not satisfied with your answer